# What does two dots before a slash mean? (../)

Tags: linux, unix, path

What does `../` mean in Linux/Unix paths? I've seen that it means as 'up a directory' but I couldn't get to understand it fully.

Comment: The unix filesystem is a hierarchy. It means to go up one level, to the directory that contains the current directory.

Comment: If your current directory is `/home/yourname/somefolder`, `..` means `/home/yourname`

Comment: Ah.. thanks for the explanation!

Comment: tip: you can go to a directory and then type `cd the_respective_folder_path/../` to test what ../ will do. Same is the case for other things like /../.. etc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each directory has two entries in it at the start, with names `.` (a link to itself) and `..` (a link to its parent directory).  The exception, of course, is the root directory, where the `..` directory also refers to the root directory.